# I need to have a cell that returns the value of the first condition, but if the second condition is met, I need it to return that value instead

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on a spreadsheet that needs to work with multiple conditions. I need column B to specify in which process we are "Process 1", "Process 2", "Process 3". Here the recruiters will click on a checkbox if the candidate is on process one, or if he moved to process 2 or 3. If the first checkbox is true, it will say "Process 1", but if the second checkbox is true, i need for it to say "Process 2" regardless that the first condition is still "true", because it would be very annoying having to uncheck the boxes.
Columns with checkboxes are: J, R and Z
Hope I was clear enough with my question! Also, if there is another way besides checkboxes I'm open to suggestions!

[image]

`=IF(J6=TRUE,"Proceso 1",IF(R6=TRUE,"Proceso 2",IF(Z6=TRUE,"Proceso 3","Chequear Proceso")))`

I've tried with a normal if statement, but it will always return the value of the first true condition. I need the value of the last true condition

Comment: Reverse the order of the checks: IF(Z6=TRUE,"Proceso 3",IF(R6=TRUE,"Proceso 2",IF(J6=TRUE,"Proceso 1","Chequear Proceso")))

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=ifs(Z6,"Proceso 3",R6,"Proceso 2",J6,"Proceso 1",1,"Chequear Proceso")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers!! They were really helpful! What if I wanted to do the same but add to it another column. We have columns Q, Y and AG that determine the stage for each process (e.g. screening or local interview). So now column A is the one that determines the process (Process 1, 2 or 3), and I want for column B to be which stage the candidate is in the respective process, for example, candidate is in process 2 and he is on screening stage, without taking into consideration the previous process that he was in

Answer (score 0):

In response to your statement:  "**Also, if there is another way besides checkboxes I'm open to suggestions!**", here is another interesting alternative.  Treat your checkboxes like radio buttons with the following script, if that is an option you would like to explore.

```
/**
 * onEdit to uncheck checkboxes as required
 */
function onEdit(e) {
   
  // get event object data: sheet name, row number and column number
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const row = e.range.rowStart;
  const col = e.range.columnStart;

  // Rows 2 through 12, Columns J through L
  if (e.range.rowStart > 2 || e.range.rowStart < 13 || e.range.colStart > 9 || e.range.colStart < 12 ) {

  switch(col) {
 
    // case when column J is checked
    case 10:
      sheet.getRange("K" + row + ":L" + row).uncheck();
      break;
 
    // case when column K is checked
    case 11:
      sheet.getRangeList(["J" + row,"M" + row]).uncheck();
      break;
     
    // case when column L is checked
    case 12:
      sheet.getRange("J" + row + ":K" + row).uncheck();
      break;
 
    // cell is outside of columns K to M
    default:
      return;
  
  }
  }
}
```

Change the range as desired.  Specify particular sheet, as well, if desired to limit the script to only run when this sheet is edited.